# Merging older versions of a file within Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have a file which has been checked out in a dynamic view and modified a certain time ago without being checked in, I'll call this *version i*. In the mean time the development branch has moved on and several newer versions (*j*, *k* and then *l*) of the same file have been checked in from other views. I need to merge the modifications of version i and l. I can't simply check *version i* in because that generates a "predecessor is not latest" error.

Is there a safe (and simple) way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One safest way is to:

- checkout `l`, and then
- use a third-party merge tool ([`kdiff3`](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for instance) to merge `i` (source) with `l` (destination, checked out).
- Then check in a new merged version `m`.

Finally, you can undo checkout `i` in the first dynamic view, allowing that version to update itself automatically (dynamically) to the latest version '`m`' (result of the merge)

Comment: I was hoping for a Clearcase solution since the list of tools I'm allowed to use is limited, but alright I guess this is an unusual situation.